# Laravel [5.3] custom validation get key of array in rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to ask about custom validation in laravel.

Controller :

```
$rules = [
        'start_time.*'      => 'required|date_format:H:i:s',
        'end_time.*'        => 'required|date_format:H:i:s|total_times:5,hours',
    ];
```

Service Provider :

```
Validator::extendImplicit('total_times', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $getData = (object) $validator->getData();

    ?? how to know key of array this value ??

});
```

Comment: Which version of laravel u are using?\

Comment: in the title, laravel 5.3

Comment: Its laravel 5.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `$attribute` value.

```
Validator::extendImplicit('total_times', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   $key = str_replace('end_time.', '', $attribute);
});
```

Or `$key = preg_replace('/^([^\.]+)\.(.+)$/', "\\2", $attribute);` if you use it for different fields

Comment: I also think the same way with you, and add logic if $attribute is array or not. 
I thought in parameter $validator have some kind of function to know key of array this value, like as $validator->getData(). Thanks.